# Assign Class Methods to an already established element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, loops, assign

I'm developing some Ruby projects. I'm still learning some basic tenets of Ruby, but I need some help with a particular problem I've been having.
I need to assign some already-created elements with the methods associated with a class. How can I go about doing that?
Here's my example.

Let's say that I have an array of arrays

```
my_pets = ['Buddy the iguana', 'Coco the cat', 'Dawn the parakeet']
```

And I also have a class for which I've written a particular function that I need the my_pets array to access. Basically, this function loops through an array of strings and replaces the "a" with "@".

```
class Cool_Pets

    def a_replace(array)
        array.each do |string|
            if string.include?("a")
                string.gsub!(/a/, "@")
            end
        end
     puts string
   end

end
```

Is there a way to assign my_pets as part of the Cool_Pets class so that it can use the a_replace method?

Here's my desired result:

```
a_replace(my_pets) = ['Buddy the igu@na', 'Coco the c@t', 'D@wn the p@r@keet']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) here:

```
my_pets.map{ |s| s.gsub(/a/,'@') }
#=> ["Buddy the igu@n@", "Coco the c@t", "D@wn the p@r@keet"]
```

Your code almost works, just remove `puts array` and the `if` statement. Then just call the function.

```
#Use CamelCase for class names NOT snake_case.
#Using two spaces for indentation is sensible.
class CoolPets 
  def a_replace(array)
    array.each do |string|
      string.gsub!(/a/, "@")
    end
  end
end

cool = CoolPets.new
my_pets = ['Buddy the iguana', 'Coco the cat', 'Dawn the parakeet']
p cool.a_replace(my_pets)
#=> ["Buddy the igu@n@", "Coco the c@t", "D@wn the p@r@keet"]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. However, the reason I'm asking is because I specifically want to know if reassigning the my_pets array to the Cool_Pets class is possible (and whether that kind of method is possible in general). Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! Actually, your suggestion helped considerably and I was able to move forwards in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but check out **Mixins**: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html#S2

```
module CoolPet
  def a_replace(array)
    array.each do |string|
      if string.include?("a")
        string.gsub!(/a/, "@")
      end
    end

    puts array.inspect
  end
end

class MyPet
  include CoolPet
end

array = ['Buddy the iguana', 'Coco the cat', 'Dawn the parakeet']
pet = MyPet.new
pet.a_replace(array) # => ["Buddy the igu@n@", "Coco the c@t", "D@wn the p@r@keet"]
```